# Динамическое изменение значения заголовка при наличии NavBar и TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

Имеется следующая схема с Navigation Controller & Tab Bar Controller.
Как при такой схеме изменять значение Title в зависимости от выбранного Item?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте кастомный `UITabBarController`

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.title = self.tabBar.selectedItem?.title
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        self.navigationItem.title = item.title
    }
}
```

и в сториборде выставте ваш клас `UITabBarController`у

[image]

Comment: Этот вариант помог. Спасибо. Один вопрос из любопытства: почему у функции viewWillAppear вызываем super.viewWillAppear(animated), а в случае функции tabBar нет?

Comment: потому что `viewWillAppear` это переопределение метода класса `UIViewController` в котором он уже был реализован,  а `func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)` это опциональный метод делегата `UITabBarDelegate` (`UITabBarController ` хоть и реализует это делегат но метод этот там не определен). Ради интереса попробуйте вписать `super.tabBar...` а потом запустить  и все станет понятно

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Но тогда я не совсем уловил значение ключевого слова override... разве оно не указывает на факт переопределения? При этом получается, что данное ключевое слово используется оба раза, но переопределение лишь в одном случае из двух...

Comment: @Имя все верно override используется указывая на факт переопределения, поэтому в обоих случаях нужно вызывать super, но во втором лучше после того как вы задали значение, так рекомендует Apple. 
Если же ваш другой класс будет реализовывать UITabBarDelegate, то естественно там не будет override этих методов.
Это же можно наблюдать с наследованием от UITableViewController и реализацией UITableViewDelegate/Datasource в UIViewController (в первом случае будет override, а во втором просто реализация протокола).